# Change the color of the correct option in beamer

Tags: beamer, color

[image]Command \True in package ex_test to color the correct answer in a question during the slide show. But I need to use two frames to do that, one without \True, one with \True. How can I do it with only 1 frame. Sorry for my English. Thank you very much.

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
        \begin{ex}
            In this box, do not color the true answer
            \choice
            {answer1}
            {answer2}
            {answer3}
            {answer4}
        \end{ex}
\end{frame}

\setcounter{ex}{0}
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \begin{ex}
        In this box, color the true answer
        \choice
        {\True answer1}
        {answer2}
        {answer3}
        {answer4}
    \end{ex}
\end{frame}
```

Link overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/3696313321nqzcsxrjdcsh

Comment: Welcome! Please post code that can be compiled on our side; you should prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Otherwise it's almost impossible to be of any help.

Comment: Your link is not shared.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the link again.

Answer (score 2):

You could change the command from the `ex_test` package to automatically create a second overlay:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,t,hyperref={pdfpagemode=FullScreen}]{beamer}
\makeatletter
\let\th@plain\relax
\makeatother
\usepackage[color]{ex_test}
\renewtheorem{ex}{\color{blue!50!black} \small \fontfamily{qag}\selectfont Question}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}        
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{framed}

\makeatletter
\def\colorEX{\only<2>{\color{red}}}
\renewcommand{\begindapan}{
\@ifnextchar\True
{
\begin{minipage}[t]{\widthalpha}
\alt<2>{\TrueEX}{\FalseEX}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dorong}
}
{
\begin{minipage}[t]{\widthalpha}
\FalseEX
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dorong}
}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{ans}
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \setcounter{ex}{0}
        \begin{ex}
            In this box, do not color the true answer
            \choice
            {\True answer1}
            {answer2}
            {answer3}
            {answer4}
        \end{ex}
\end{frame}


\Closesolutionfile{ans}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is all I need, thank you so much samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz.

Comment: @NguyễnCảnhDũng You're welcome!